# Create API acceess to SQL Server Express 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have kind of simple issue but fail to resolve it.
Here's the issue: I have SQL Server Express 2014 installed on my PC. I have to use SQL Server authentication because it should work when network is down. As sa I created login and user e.g. user1. Then as user1 I created DB e.g. db1 and a few tables. Now I could login into db1 as user1 using SQL Server authentication. The problem is that this db1 will be used by application e.g. app1. This app1 has configuration file that has all credentials and other connection strings things. Well when I start that application it throws error "Can't connect to database". Then I look into log and see this: Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8. Login failed for user 'user1'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided [CLIENT: . 
Then I could disable credential check in configuration file of app1 and then I don't have problem to start app1 but I have to use credential check.
Then I tried to created ODBC connection and use the same credentials and I succeed to connect.
Could some give the idea what could be wrong and I can't connect to db1 from my app1?
Thanks

Comment: I'm all set now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

All set, Thanks for info. I installed client 2008 R2 and now it's working. The problem was with the type of authentication. In my case it was equal 'true' and expected exact SQL user password which I was not able to pass because it was encrypted. When I change the type to 'false' it started to use Windows authentication and that resolved my problem.

Ticket could be closed